# Save strings from text file into array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, text-files

My text file is like

```
Alex Garcia 1000 userid password
Sana Lopez 300 uid pwd
```

I am trying to save above text file in 2D array

```
ifstream Records("customerdata.txt");
string dataarray[6][6];

    if (Records.is_open())
     {
         while ( Records.good() )
            {
                for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<6; j++)
                    {
                        getline(Records,dataarray[i][j],' ');

                    }


                }
            }
        Records.close();
    }
     else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

When I try to output array using for loop I get some values missing. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I highly recommend searching StackOverflow for "[C++] text file array".  There have been too many of these questions lately.

Comment: Also search for "[c++] parse input file".

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ read text file into array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918084/c-read-text-file-into-array)

Answer (score 0):

You need to tokenize each of the lines you read in using something like this, plus your datarray is larger than the number of records read in, you only have two rows not 6.

```
ifstream Records("customerdata.txt");
string dataarray[6][6];

  if (Records.is_open())
   {
          while ( Records.good() )
          {
             size_t row=0;
             size_t col=0;
             std::string myLine;
             getline(Records,myLine);
             std::istringstream nlineSteam(myLine);
             std::string token;
             while(nlineSteam >> token){
              dataarray[row][col]=token;
              col++;
             }
             row++;
             col=0;

          }
    Records.close();
}
 else cout << "Unable to open file";
```